# Output float to debug

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I was wondering if there was an alternative to OutputDebugString but for floats instead?  As I want to be able to view in the output in Visual studio the values.

Comment: Well you could wsprintf the float to a buffer and OutputDebugString that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert your float to a string

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << 2.5;
std::string s(ss.str());
```

Then print your newly made string with this

```
OutputDebugString(s.c_str());
```

Optionaly you can skip the intermediate string with

```
OutputDebugString(ss.str().c_str());
```

Comment: But OutputDebugString() does not accept a [const char *]  as an input! It needs to be converted to LPCWSTR first.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I combined Eric's answer and Toran Billups' answer from 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27296/7011474
To get:</s>

```
std::wstring d2ws(double value) {
    return s2ws(d2s(value));
}

std::string d2s(double value) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << value;
    return oss.str();
}

std::wstring s2ws(const std::string& s)
{
    int len;
    int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
    len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0);
    wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[len];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, buf, len);
    std::wstring r(buf);
    delete[] buf;
    return r;
}

double theValue=2.5;
OutputDebugString(d2ws(theValue).c_str());
```

Edit: Thanks to Quentin's comment there's an easier way:

```
std::wstring d2ws(double value) {
    std::wostringstream woss;
    woss << value;
    return woss.str();
}

double theValue=2.5;
OutputDebugString(d2ws(theValue).c_str());
```

Comment: Um... There's `std::wostringstream` which does it all already.

Comment: Did not know that. Thank you.